# List<T> is cleared problem

Tags: c#, list

Please take a look at the code. It shouldn't take long to have a glimpse.

```
class Teacher
    {
        private int _id;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set { _message = value; }
        }

        public Teacher(int id, string msg)
        {
            _id = id;
            _message = msg;
        }

        private List<Course> _items;
        public List<Course> GetCourses()
        {
            return _items;
        }

        public Teacher()
        {
            if (_items == null)
            {
                _items = new List<Course>();
            }

            _items.Add(new Course(1, "cpp"));
            _items.Add(new Course(1, "java"));
            _items.Add(new Course(1, "cs"));
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this._id);
            Console.WriteLine(this._message);
        }

        public void ShowList()
        {
            foreach(Course c in _items)
            {
                c.Show();
            }
        }
    }

    class Course
    {
        private int _id;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set { _message = value; }
        }

        public Course(int id, string msg)
        {
            _id = id;
            _message = msg;
        }

        private List<Teacher> _items;
        public List<Teacher> GetTeachers()
        {
            return _items;
        }

        public Course()
        {
            if(_items == null)
            {
                _items = new List<Teacher>();
            }

            _items.Add(new Teacher(1, "ttt"));
            _items.Add(new Teacher(1, "ppp"));
            _items.Add(new Teacher(1, "mmm"));
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this._id);
            Console.WriteLine(this._message);
        }

        public void ShowList()
        {
            foreach (Teacher t in _items)
            {
                t.Show();
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Teacher t = new Teacher();
            t.ID = 1;
            t.Message = "Damn";

            t.Show();
            t.ShowList();

            t.GetCourses().Clear();

            t.Show();
            t.ShowList();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Since `GetCourse()` returns a reference of _items, calling `t.GetCourses().Clear();` is clearing the underlying `Course`-list in the `Teacher` instance.

I want to prevent this behaviour. That is, the `GetCourse()` would return a list but it would not be modifiable.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could create a copy of the list, or wrap it in ReadOnlyCollection:

```
private List<Course> _items;
public IList<Course> GetCourses()
{
    return new List<Course>(_items);
}
```

or

```
private List<Course> _items;
public IList<Course> GetCourses()
{
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<Course>(_items);
}
```

The first option creates an independent list - the caller will be able to modify it, adding or removing items, but those changes won't be seen in the teacher object's list. The second option is just a wrapper around the existing list - so any changes to the collection will be visible through the wrapper. The caller won't be able to make any changes to the collection.

Note that in both cases, if the `Course` objects referenced by the list have their data changed, those changes will be visible either way - you'd have to clone each `Course` if you want to stop that happening.

Comment: Is this how it's done in C# now? I'm out of the C# loop, but would you make a new List like that or would you somehow clone the list? I would suspect that the List contains a method to deep-copy the list.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't think there's anything in `List<T>` to create a deep clone. Cloning is largely discouraged in my experience.

Answer (score 5):

How about returning an `IEnumerable<Course>` instead?

***Slightly off topic:*** If you really do want to return a list that can be added to, cleared, et cetera, you should probably return a `Collection<T>` instead of a `List<T>`, or maybe even one of the interfaces, for example `ICollection<T>`. In general I would say you should always return the most restrictive type that you can, since it is easier to loosen up things like that than to narrow it down later.

Comment: A caller could cast that back to List<Course> and still modify the underlying list.